# Running “exists” queries in Laravel query builder

Tags: php, mysql, html, laravel

I'm trying to execute this :

```
SELECT * FROM `lms_test` 
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
   (SELECT * FROM `lms_studenttest` 
    WHERE `lms_test`.slug = `lms_studenttest`.testId 
    AND `lms_studenttest`.`studentId`='10a75c804b8851520993dedc42334c0f'
    ) 
AND `lms_test`.`testType`= 'Practice Test'
```

But not getting success.
Help me to do this.

Comment: [I think you best can rewrite it to](https://explainextended.com/2009/09/15/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-sql-server/) `where null`. I'm not sure however.

Comment: Hi there, welcome to SO! Please, try to be more precise in your question,  some debug output my be helpful, too. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this example :

```
A::whereNotExists(function($query){
  $query->select(DB::raw(1))
        ->from('B')
        ->whereRaw('A.id = B.id');
  })
 ->get();
```

OR

```
DB::table('lms_test')
        ->whereNotExists(function ($query) {
            $query->select('lms_studenttest.*')
                  ->from('lms_studenttest')
                  ->where('lms_test.testType', 'Practice Test')
                  ->where('lms_studenttest.studentId', '10a75c804b8851520993dedc42334c0f')
                  ->whereRaw('lms_studenttest.testId = lms_test.slug');
        })
        ->get();
```

Hope this help for you !!!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
DB::table('lms_test')
        ->whereNotExists(function ($query) {
            $query->select(DB::raw(1))
                  ->from('lms_studenttest')
                  ->where('lms_test.testType', 'Practice Test')
                  ->where('lms_studenttest.studentId', '10a75c804b8851520993dedc42334c0f')
                  ->whereRaw('lms_studenttest.testId = lms_test.slug');
        })
        ->where('testType','Practice Test')
        ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this (I don't check it on real data , I wrote only logic):

```
SELECT *
    FROM `lms_test` 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN `lms_studenttest`
        ON `lms_test`.slug = lms_studenttest`.testId 
        WHERE `lms_studenttest`.testId IS NULL
        AND `lms_studenttest`.`studentId`='10a75c804b8851520993dedc42334c0f'
        AND `lms_test`.`testType`= 'Practice Test'
```

Comment: He asked for the laravel query builder equivalent of the query he provided, not a different raw SQL query

Answer (score -1):

Try the following conditional query and let me know if its help:

```
if (User::where('email', '=', Input::get('email'))->exists()) {
  // user found
}
```